# Can't instantiate class from installed extension when run via OSGI

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

So, I have an installed extension (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/index.html) which I can see in Eclipse.

I've written a simple rcp application that tries to create an instance of a class in this extension. However, although everything compiles ok, I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError when creating the instance.

I'm assuming this has something to do with OSGi because I can run a simple java application that creates the instance fine.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see the class package loaded in the import list of your manifest ?

Comment: No, its not there. I was under the impression that, because its an installed extension, it is considered part of the standard jre and therefore there is an implied import.

Comment: Nope as @earcam explained, it unfortunately needs to be explicit. Alternatively there are plugins for which you can enable auto import (which will basically pack your final artifact with all your references). Those however tend to make your stuff far more obese that they need to be tho. Entirely up to you. Whichever way, you need to make sure your references are explicitly declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found another solution which is to set the parent classloader to the 'ext' classloader using the arg

```
osgi.parentClassloader=ext
```

Not sure yet the implications of such a change other than I now don't get the error.

Comment: +1 Interesting, didn't know about this - you should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As your extension's classes are being provided by the JRE, they need to be exported by the OSGi framework's system bundle.

This can be achieved by adding the package(s) to the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` property (you can set this as a system property and it will be passed into the framework).

Once this is done and your consuming bundle has those packages listed in the Import-Package entry of it's MANIFEST.MF, you should be able access the classes.

JRE extensions are almost the antithesis of OSGi - I'm curious to know why you're doing this?

Comment: The reason is that we've moved away from sun's jre and unfortunately we have some code that has a dependancy on sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal stuff, which lived inside the rt.jar but has been moved into the ext directory of the this new jre.

Thanks for the solution. Ive added system.bundle as a required bundle and added sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal as an imported package however eclipse is telling me that no bundle exports the package.

I've set the property in the launch config but i'm assuming I need to set that property somewhere else so that its picked up at compile time too.