# Equinox and dependency on ext

Tags: java, osgi, modularity

I have an Equinox OSGi application that requires JDK's nashorn.jar, which is per default in the ext directory of the JRE8. However, when using an OSGi bundle, this dependency is not found, although I was under the impression that the files in the JRE8's ext directory are part of the boot classpath.

Is there a way to specify the classpath of the Equinox launcher to include the ext directory of the JRE? (I cannot just rebundle the JAR in question because the license does not allow this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `-Dosgi.parentClassloader=ext`, as in question [Can't instantiate class from installed extension when run via OSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337959/cant-instantiate-class-from-installed-extension-when-run-via-osgi)